# Is Mirantis OpenStack free

Tags: cloud, openstack

I have been looking onto Mirantis website and others but could not figure out if Mirantis OpenStack is free to use or not.

There are many links of web including this one https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/91456/mirantis-openstack-with-ha-includes-cost/ which says that you only pay for support and software for Mirantis OpenStack is free but answer was not accepted, can someone please confirm if it is really free to use for production? and I can get this from here: https://www.mirantis.com/software/openstack/download/

Comment: https://content.mirantis.com/contact-us-landing-page.html

Comment: but I simply wants to know whether it is free or paid... not about per licensing/device or other.

Comment: So ask them, or Google it up. It's off-topic here.